# Google Sheets Script, Hide Row(s) Based on Multiple Cell Values Triggered By Checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to find a working script to trigger onEdit when a checkbox is ticked. I will need it to be able to function for multiple checkboxes and have the script check cells for a value of "X". If that value is found then I want to hide that row

Finally I will need another script (or function) to clear all checkboxes in row 3 and (unhide) the hidden rows when a "Clear All" checkbox is checked (value is true), and then set its own value back to false when completed

If there is any better way to accomplish this I am happy to hear. I do not want to use filters

Please refer to the screenshot below of my sheet (Allergen Chart) so that it makes a bit more sense

I need the checkboxes in row 3 [columns C-P] to be the onEdit triggers for the script to run, and hide any rows that contain an X in that column

Allergen Chart[image]